# Subtracting time to get age

Tags: go

My aim is to calculate the age of the pod by doing the subtraction of "current_time - pod_creation_time" so that I will get the age, I am getting creation time from metadata but it's in the format "2021-07-13 16:34:22 +0530 IST", so when I trying to subtract it from `time.Now()`, I am getting parsing error like below:

invalid operation: "t2 : " + t2 (mismatched types string and time.Time)

Anyone could please help how to have creation time "2021-07-13 16:34:22 +0530 IST" from metadata in the proper format so that I can do "time.Now - (creation time)"

I tried some workaround like below:

creatTime, err := time.Parse("2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST",

pod.ObjectMeta.CreationTimestamp.String())

and then subtracted creationTime from Current Time. It works, but I think this is not the right way.

Comment: well you're doing it right I think :) You have to parse the string into a `time.Time` struct, which you are doing with the `time.Parse` function. The only thing you can do different is to use the `time.Since()` function instead of substracting the date from the current time.

Answer (score 1):

There's a type mismatch as `time.Now()` return the current time stored in the type `time.Time` whereas `2021-07-13 16:34:22 +0530 IST` is a string. You can perform the required subtraction operation on mismatched types i.e., `time.Time` and `string`.

You have to parse the string by specifying the layout. I'd recommend reading the [time](https://pkg.go.dev/time#pkg-constants) package's doc.

I've explained every operation in the sample code below; I hope it helps. If you understand this, you can also then look at helper functions like `time.Since` that can help you write the same program in fewer lines.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    // K8s timestamp
    t := "2021-07-13 16:34:22 +0530 IST"

    // Format of K8s timestamp
    format := "2006-01-02 15:04:05 -0700 MST" // Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006

    // Parse the timestamp so that it's stored in time.Time
    cur, err := time.Parse(format, t)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    // Current time
    now := time.Now()

    // As both are of type time.Time, it's subtractable
    dur := now.Sub(cur)

    // Print duration
    fmt.Println(dur)

    // Print duration (in seconds)
    fmt.Println(dur.Seconds())
}
```

Comment: @AtharwaMokasdar Could you mark the answer as accepted? Green tick helps others when are searching for answers.